# Expected distance between two random nodes in weighted tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, probability-theory

Given an undirected connected graph with *N* nodes and *N-1* edges.

Out of *N*  nodes, *1...k* nodes are selected, out of which 2 nodes are selected randomly (uniformly).

How do I calculate the expected distance between those 2 points?

By the way, I tried using sum of distance between all pairs of *k* nodes and divided it by *k* to get the distance. Denominator is correct. But this gives wrong answer. How do I correct the approach?

Comment: Sorry, your question is still not clear, what is the problem with your current approach? Is it of high complexity? Are the numbers too big so when you sum them up you get overflows? What is the problem with the "numerator getting too large"? What kind of answer are you expecting?

Comment: @aelguindy suppose for a graph I get my numerator as 89 but the numerator was only 29. I'm just talking about the error because I calculated distance between all pairs of nodes which is not the correct approach.

Comment: How are these $k$ nodes selected? What exactly is the input of the algorithm, aside from the tree? What is the problem with your approach? While brute-force, it seems to be correct.